# Smart Group relative date criteria not saving

Tags: smartgroups, dates

There is a history of a bug in which Smart Groups do not store the proper relative date ("Next 60 days") criteria, but rather convert the relative date into a hard date ("3 Jan 2018" to "4 Mar 2018"). This bug was noticed starting with v. 4.7.x and was. [supposedly fixed in 4.7.13](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19394) I'm still having this issue in 4.7.27 (Joomla 3.8.2).

Anyone else notice this recurring? Any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recall we've experienced this for quite a number of fields in Advanced Search. Some of them are - `Event Dates`, `Registration Dates` and some date filters in Case section.

I did a patch to fix this for us but missed to update core for some reason. If the above fields fail for you, can you try applying [this patch](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11486) and see if it works for you?

Opened a [JIRA](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21623) for this issue with a PR https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11486.

Comment: Thanks! The patch works! I wasn't ready to open a JIRA myself since it was supposedly fixed before, so thanks for your efforts on fixing it. One ... quirk ... though: while the saved search/smart group keeps the relative date, the text describing what the search is (when viewing the list of names) does not use relative language, i.e. <<Start Date - greater than or equal to "January 4th, 2018 12:00 AM" ...AND... End Date - less than or equal to "March 4th, 2018 11:59 PM">> rather than <<Event Date - Next 60 days>>. Not a big deal, but potentially confusing for users.

Comment: ok, in my view, it actually provides more information, so that a user is known about the dates considered in the relative filter `This Month`, `This quarter`, etc. I personally like this date display rather than seeing the string filter I selected :-)

Comment: I can see it both ways. I guess in my context where I don't have confidence that the search is saving the dates correctly, having hard dates displayed with the results doesn't increase my confidence that it is working properly.