# Smart Groups and 'event dates'

Tags: civievent, smartgroups, dates

might there still (or again) be an issue with 4.7.27 on wordpress like this?

[How to use Smart Groups with relative dates?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/14432/how-to-use-smart-groups-with-relative-dates/22065)

i'd need to create a dynamic group based on the 'register date' for any event in the date range 'last week' - but it never seems to get updated, the from/to dates look like they're set statically after saving the dynamic group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be related to [Smart Group relative date criteria not saving](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/22046/smart-group-relative-date-criteria-not-saving) and there is fix for it https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11486

Please let me know if that works for you.

Comment: yes, this seems to fix it for my current case.also approved on github.